# How do you check if a specific position is a letter character in python?

Tags: python

I know that in order to see if a variable has only letters you use .isalpha, but what if I'm trying to see if a specific position in the string is a letter? How would I code that?

Answer (score 3):

```
my_string[a_position].isalpha()
```

...

a character is just a string with one letter ...

Comment: You might want to add "and indexing (or for that matter slicing) a string gives you another string"